# Understanding the algebra for simplifying the cut size in graph partitioning

Tags: graph-theory

I am reading this paper about graph partitioning and I am trying to understand how they have simplified the cut size R.
[image: 1st section of the paper]

[image: 2nd section of the paper]

I get everything up to the last sum in equation 7. I am not sure how they have added $s_{i}s_{j}\delta_{ij}$ to the last sum. Any help would be much appreciated.

Also if someone could explain how we can convert the equation (8) into the following matrix form $R=\frac{1}{2}s^{T}Ls$, where L is the Laplacian matrix, that would be very helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\sum_i \sum_j s_i s_j k_i \delta_{ij}
= \sum_i s_i k_i \sum_j s_j \delta_{ij}
= \sum_i s_i k_i \sum_{j: i = j} s_j
= \sum_i s_i k_i s_i
= \sum_i s_i^2 k_i
$$